# SetInterval(timespan, func) in console .NET?

Tags: .net, multithreading

I have a .NET console app and every 5mins when my code is blocking (console.readline()) i'd like to run a task on the side. I also have other threads which may need to run a task in X mins later if they are blocking. Is there something like `SetInterval(timespan, func)` in .NET?

Comment: You could use variuos `timers` [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) or [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx). Excluding, of course, Windows.Timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is.  [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx), or [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), depending on your needs.  See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) for a comparison of the various timers.

As Steve mentions in the comments, the only one that is clearly inappropriate is System.Windows.Forms.Timer (because it requires a message pump, which you don't (usually) have in a console app).

Comment: System.Timers.Timer seems like the most comfortable to use.